# Load auto load only once

Tags: php, frameworks, composer-php, autoloader

I am using autoloader.php using composer.json

```
"autoload": {
   "classmap": [

        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
             "App\\Helpers\\": "app/lib/Helpers",
             "App\\Traits\\": "app/Traits",

        }
  }
```

and in index.php i have

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

if accss any class using object in index.php its working fine.Now my problem is i have to load    `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` in every class to works fine.is there any method to add it only once in start up.

for example

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Controllers\HomeController;

$myclass = new HomeController(); 
$myclass->index();
```

above code works since i have used  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';. i have created one more file in another directory

```
<?php
namespace App\test;

use App\Controllers\HomeController;

$myclass = new HomeController(); 
$myclass->index();
```

Here also i have add once again require once. now m trying to avoid including every time includeing autoload.php
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You only need to include the Composer Autoloader once in your application.
A good place is the `index.php` file, which acts as the central entry point to your application.

`index.php`:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// handle the $_GET parameters (e.g. `index.php?controller=home&action=index`)
// translate them to your controller object
// then call the controller and action requested
// hardcoded for now:

$controller = new \App\Controllers\HomeController(); 
$controller->index();
```

`HomeController.php`:

```
<?php
// this controller is instantiated after `index.php`, 
// 'index.php' loaded the Composer Autoloader already.
// Autoloading is available at this point. 
// There is no need to set it up again.

namespace App\Controllers;

class HomeController
{
    public function index() 
    { 
        echo 'Hello from HomeController->index()';
    }
}
```